# How to prove a function is less than $0$ for all real value of $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to show a function is less than $0$ for all real value of $x$?

For example, what's the methods of showing $$x-\sqrt{x^2+1}<0$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well in this case $x^2 + 1 > x^2 \ge 0$ so $\sqrt {x^2 + 1} > \sqrt {x^2} = |x|$.  So $x - \sqrt{x^2 + 1} < x - |x|$.  If $x \ge 0$ $x - |x| = 0$.  If $x < 0$ then $x - |x| < -|x| < 0$.  Either way $x -|x| \le 0$.

Comment: $$x\leq \sqrt{x^2}<\sqrt{x^2+1}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Rewrite it as $$x < \sqrt{x^2+1}$$ and then consider whether this is true for positive, negative and zero $x$

Answer (score 3):

It's obvious that $x^2+1 > x^2$ for all real $x$, since $1>0$. Then, take square roots of both sides, you have $\sqrt{x^2+1} > |x|$. By definition of $|x|$, $|x|\geq x$ so we have $\sqrt{x^2+1} > x$. subtracting $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ from both sides gives the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

If $x<0\rightarrow x-\sqrt{x^{2}+1}<0$ (clearly)

If $x\geq 0, \quad x^{2}+1>x^{2}\rightarrow \sqrt{x^{2}+1}>x\rightarrow x-\sqrt{x^{2}+1}<0$

Answer (score 0):

Well, $x^2+1> x^2$ so $\sqrt{x^2+1}>|x|\geq x$

Answer (score 0):

See if $x=\sqrt{x^2+1}$ has any solutions (hint: it doesn't). Then, take any value of $x$ and plug it in to $f(x)=x-\sqrt{x^2+1}$. If the value for $f$ is negative, then $f(x)<0$ for all $x$. This is due to the continuity of $f$, and the fact that $f$ has no roots.

Answer (score 0):

Notice if $0 < a < b$ then $\sqrt{a} < \sqrt{b}$.

[If $\sqrt a \ge \sqrt b \ge 0$ then $a = \sqrt a\sqrt a \ge \sqrt a \sqrt b \ge \sqrt b \sqrt b = b$.  That is a contradiction so $\sqrt a < \sqrt b$.]

So $\sqrt {x^2 + 1} > \sqrt {x^2} = |x| \ge x$.

So $x < \sqrt{x^2 + 1}$.

So $x - \sqrt{x^2 + 1}< 0$.